# Is this a sufficient condition for the absolute continuity of the measure?

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $\{\mu_t\}_{t\in [0, T]}$ measures on the interval $[0,1]$. Suppose that

$$\sup_{\phi\in L^1[0,1], \|\phi\|\leq 1, \phi\geq 0}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^1\phi(x)d\mu_t(x)<+\infty$$.

Is this condition enough to conclude that the measure $\mu_t$ is absolutely continuous respect to the Lesbegue measure for a.e. $t\in [0, T]$? Reading some notes I found a step like that but I don't understand why and I am not even sure that I understood correctly. Could someone help me?

Comment: I think you've lost $dt$ along the way

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you

Comment: What does "$L^1[0,1]$" mean?  With respect to which measure?  If it's not a measure that $\mu_t$ is absolutely continuous to, then $\int \phi(x) d\mu_t(x)$ is not well defined.

Comment: Perhaps they really mean the sup over all nonnegative Borel functions $\phi$, with $\|\phi\|_{L^1([0,1], m)} \le 1$, rather than over elements of $L^1$ (which are equivalence classes).

Comment: There should also be some condition on how $\mu_t$ depends on $t$, in order to ensure that $t \mapsto \int \phi\,d\mu_t$ is measurable.

Comment: Maybe you could share a reference to the notes where you read this?  As Rhys notes, it doesn't seem to be true as you've written it, so perhaps the author meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, it is possible that the integral of $\phi$ against $\mu_t$ may not even be well defined if $\mu_t$ isn't absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. This is because $\phi \in L^1[0,1]$ is an equivalence class of functions which are equal to each other Lebesgue almost everywhere. This condition is not enough to imply that the integrals against $\mu_t$ of every member of that equivalence class is the same.

One strong assumption you could make to get around this is to assume that the $\sup$ is finite even when taken not just over non-negative elements of $L^1[0,1]$ but instead over all functions that lie in the equivalence class of a non-negative element of $L^1[0,1]$.

Even this condition is not enough to guarantee absolute continuity of $\mu_t$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure for a single $t$ in $[0,1]$, nevermind a.e. $t$. For simplicity I fix $T = 1$ here.

For each $t$ let $\mu_t = \delta_t$ be the dirac measure at $t$. Then for $\phi$ in the equivalence class of some non-negative element of $L^1[0,1]$, $$\int_0^1 \phi(x) d\mu_t(x) = \phi(t).$$

Hence we have that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \phi(x) d\mu_t(x) dt = \|\phi\|_{L^1[0,1]}$$
for all $\phi \in L^1[0,1]$ such that $\phi \geq 0$ so that your $\sup$ is finite. However, it is clear that there is no $t$ such that $\mu_t$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the lebesgue measure.